# Assigned Anonymous Functions vs Named Function Declarations

Tags: function, functional-programming, lambda, lambda-calculus

In developing a functional programming language, is it possible to make assigned anonymous function expressions equivalent to named function declarations/definitions?

For example in this pseudo language:

```
add = \ x y -> x + y -- assigned anonymous function expression
add x y = x + y -- named function declaration
```

I know that in non-functional languages, the 2 have somewhat different properties, but I'm asking why can't they be the same? Is it a compiler problem?

For example, are there languages to make the above 2 equivalent in terms of recursion? So I can recurse using their name and their assigned label?

```
factorial = \ n -> if n = 0 then 1 else n * factorial (n-1)
factorial n = if n = 0 then 1 else n * factorial (n-1)
```

Also see this: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Declaration_vs._expression_style

Comment: In which "non-functional" languages are those different, and how? In what language can't you use either of your `factorial` definitions?

Comment: JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby, Haskell... of course they have syntactic differences like `function`, `def`.. etc.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: In JavaScript, Python, Haskell, the 2 are not different. In Ruby, `def` defines methods, so there is actually no syntax that defines "named functions".

Comment: @newacct what do you call function declarations? I didn't say "named functions", I clarified referring to "named function declarations". Also defining methods are kind of equivalent to function declarations with a namespace, and a closed over reference to the namespace.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: You said "For example in this pseudo language: I know that in non-functional languages, the 2 have somewhat different properties" But that is false for almost every language you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In developing a functional programming language, is it possible to make assigned anonymous function expressions equivalent to named function declarations/definitions?

Yes, assuming your language supports named lambda functions or constructs for recursing inside lambda functions.

> I know that in non-functional languages, the 2 have somewhat different properties, but I'm asking why can't they be the same? Is it a compiler problem?

That depends on the language you're talking about.

> For example, are there languages to make the above 2 equivalent in terms of recursion? So I can recurse using their name and their assigned label?

There's a difference between anonymous functions and named functions in terms of recursion. Many functional languages solve this by having a special construct that allows you to name anonymous functions within their own scope, so that they are able to call themselves.

For instance, in Clojure you have the possibility to name a lambda function like in this expression:

```clj
(fn power [n e]
   (if (zero? e)
     1
     (* n (power n (dec e)))))
```

or in JavaScript:

```js
function power(n, e) {
  if (e === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * power(n, e - 1);
  }
}
```

Here, the symbol `power` is bound in the environment for the `power` function, but not outside. This is different from defining the function in the current environment - thus making the symbol `power` visible to others:

```clj
(defn power [n e]
   (if (zero? e)
     1
     (* n (power n (dec e)))))
```

or in JavaScript:

```js
var power = function (n, e) ...
```

but they are both equivalent functions, mathematically.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. But in the beginning of your answer, you said that they can be made equivalent. But at the bottom you identified a caveat, i.e. named function declarations can be easily recursed, but assigned anonymous functions cannot without using the fixed combinator. Doesn't that mean that named function declarations are not just syntactic sugar for assigned anonymous functions, but are actually doing something extra (that allows easy recursion)?

Comment: Could you also elaborate on that special construct?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'll elaborate in my answer.

Comment: So they can be equivalent: if the language supports *named* assigned anonymous function. But, then why can't a language assume that an assigned anonymous function is also a *named* with the same assignment?

Comment: Also your clojure example shows a named function expression, that's the same as in javascript right? Where you can have `var func = function func()..etc`. I'm wondering what the pros/cons are for the interpreter/compiler simply assuming that any assigned anonymous function is also named with that same name.

Comment: Also named anonymous functions kind of look like syntax sugar/macro for a fixed combinator. I'm wondering what the underlying implementation is. Instead of constructing a whole new function accepting the recursing function as a parameter, you name the function, thus allowing one to reference itself.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I recommend you focus on one particular language when figuring out semantics of functions, underlying implementations and stuff like that. There are no common set of rules that all functional languages follow. And js functions is a whole chapter in itself.

Comment: Ok so for clojure then, why not make assigned anonymous functions automatically named with the symbol they were assigned with?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Interesting question.. I'll elaborate more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62178/discussion-between-herman-torjussen-and-cmcdragonkai).

Answer (score 0):

I have downvoted your question, because it contains non-general (private?) terminology and self-thought-out ideas as if everybody would think as you do.

For example:

> Are there languages to make the above 2 equivalent in
>   terms of recursion? So I can recurse using their name and their
>   assigned label?

Why "make them equivalent", when it is entirely possible that in some languages they already **are** (semantically, but not syntactically) equivalent? So better question would be: In which languages are they equivalent? What is the difference between them in other languages where they are not?

Next, what is an "assigned label"? I guess it is your private terminology, you have some idea how it works, and you assume that we all share those ideas.

Let me tell you that, for example, in Haskell, we don't "assign labels". We rather bind names to values. And this we do in a referentially transparent way. Which basically means: it doesn't matter whether you write the name or the expression it is bound to.

Comment: Thank you for educating me on the proper terminology.